# How to remove the slidedown effect of bootstrap dropdown in low resolution

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I dont want the slidedown(pushing everything down) effect in low resolution, I needed the dropdown on top(not pushing everything down) effect.

This id the code

```
      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li>Dashboard</li>
              <li>FAQs</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul> 
      </div>



<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and I tried this, but it doesn't work either

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
</script>
```

See this,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What a waste of a question from me, I just put the code out of the nav li and it worked fine,

```
  <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li>Dashboard</li>
          <li>FAQs</li>
        </ul>
  </div>
```